# jquery not getting the image values on server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this javascript that's supposed to get the image's actual width and height. It works when I test locally on 127.0.0.1:8000 console logs on the snapshot [image] but on the server it fails [image] returns 0 as the image width and height.

Tried nesting the code in jquery ready but it does trigger before the image fully loads so I believe this is the issue.

here's the javascript

```
$(function() { 
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        $('.lynk-section img').each(function() {
            var width = $(this)[0].naturalWidth;
            console.log(width);
            //$(this).css('max-width', width+'px');

            var height = $(this)[0].naturalHeight;
            console.log(height);
            //$(this).css('max-height', height+'px');
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Run your code under `window.load`

Comment: this is the answer yes

Comment: Although this is not a duplicate, I highly recommend you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21742867/jquery-ready-vs-window-onload#21742922) question which deals with the difference between `$(document).ready` and `onload`, you may find it helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(function() {` and `$(document).ready(function() {` are the same thing (the first one is a shorthand), you only need one. But anyway, this will just wait for all the HTML code to be present in the page, not for the assets to be loaded. As @Rory said, `window.load` will wait for the images to be loaded, so you can then grab their dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the onload event of the image, or maybe you just have to use [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) event

```js
//....
$('img').each(function() {
  $(this).on("load", function(){
    console.log("width: ", this.naturalWidth);
    console.log("height: ", this.naturalHeight);
  });
});
//....
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x150">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x150">
```

Comment: Just FYI, the `each()` is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code under window load event.

```
$(function() { 
    $(document).on('load',function() {
        // Your code to measure image dimensions should go here.
    });
});
```

Comment: You're correct that you need the `window.load` event, however your code example doesn't do this.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I just gave him important clue. He has to write code where I have mentioned as comment.

Comment: A 'clue' isn't an answer though - and placing code where your comment is won't help. You've attached the load handler to the document, not the window, which is the important distinction. You need to run the code once the *window* has loaded as only then are the image dimensions available to be read in JS.

Comment: yea, @RoryMcCrossan, you are right. I am learning from you. :-)